# How do I correct the line-height inconsistency on input elements between webkit browsers and Firefox?

Tags: input, css

Is there a line-height discrepancy in Firefox that would be affecting the line-height on this input element? http://cure.org/curekids/

You'll see in the signup form right in the middle of the page that my email a dress input field has the text vertically aligned very awkward, whereas in Chrome, Safari and IE (*gasp*) all is well.

What's causing this inconsistency in Firefox and how should I remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on sponsor.css you have `div#sponsor-notify-me input#email-field` there this `padding:10px 10px 0;` just change this to `padding:0 10px 0;` and also change the `height:32px;` to `height:42px;`

Comment: This type of solution works great unless you need to support more than 1 line of text. Webkit, Opera, and IE all behave the same in this regard. I wonder why Firefox is different.

Answer (score 3):

All browsers have a default style for many elements, and they are not at all consistent, so the best approach to it is using a CSS Reset style sheet to remove all those default CSS rules.

The only "disadvantage" is that after including a reset you may have to add a couple more of rules, as you might have used some of the browser's defaults styles, like heading sizes for example.

I have been using the [YUI 3 CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) and it works really well, but be sure of including it before your CSS.

Comment: I use Eric Meyer's reset in my main stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Webkit based browsers treat line-height differently and this affects input elements. One work-around that worked for me was to use the same values for line-height and height in the css properties for each element.

e.g.

```
#button{        
    vertical-align: middle;          
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px; /* Firefox needs this to be equal to height */
}
```

You could take a look at this issue as well:
[Font height changes between Firefox & Webkit browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199380/font-height-changes-between-firefox-webkit-browsers)