# Font height changes between Firefox & Webkit browsers?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

The font (myriad pro) seems to be different between Firefox & Webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari). I have not tested on Internet Explorer.

[image: Firefox & webkit comparison]

```
form.standard.small input[type=submit] {
    width: 104px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 12px 2px 4px;
    padding: 5px 27px 5px 45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background:url('../images/button-small.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

When I go into the computed style in Firebug, all parameters are the same (line-height, font-size, padding, margin, etc). I tried isolating the @font-face files to a single .ttf file type, but no change.

Anyone know why/how to fix?

Comment: Are you sure it's only Myriad Pro that's different? *All* text renders differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360665/font-size-different-in-webkit-and-moz-browsers

Comment: @thirtydot I tried replacing the font with Arial and found little to no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that firefox adds extra height to buttons, try add this code to the css file:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
}
```

Comment: Any way to have this apply to all text elements on the page? The Same is happening (notably) to my <li> text...

Comment: Hmm basically the only css bug iv'e noticed so far in firefox is this extra space in input button, if its something else like you said <li>, try maybe change the line-height/magrin/padding sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that IE 6 do not underdstands the

```
input[type="button"]
```

You have to add a class.

Comment: I am aware of this- this particular site isn't made to have complete browser support